# My botched ordering task

Tags: word-property

I've messed up once again. I was supposed to put this group of words in order... Even though I'm sure I've alphabetized them correctly, I've been told that my solution is completely wrong! I can't take this anymore. Can anyone give me a sign and show me how to complete my task?

> BUSINESS | CHEESE | DAYS | EYES | FLY | FORD | HOLE | PACK | PEN | POTATO | SHOE | WOODS

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A compatible answer is

> PACK |  FORD | WOODS| HOLE | FLY | EYES | SHOE | CHEESE | BUSINESS | POTATO | DAYS | PEN

If these are ordered according to the

> Chinese zodiac animals:
>  Rat pack, Oxford, Tiger Woods, Rabbit hole, Dragonfly, Snake eyes, Horseshoe, Goat cheese, Monkey business, Rooster potato, Dog days, Pigpen

Comment: how do you people make this kind of logic leaps? I am genuinely fascinated and definitely feeling I am missing some important brain cells.

Comment: @htmlcoderexe One tip on this type of puzzle - *always count the number of items*. Then *ask yourself if there is anything which regularly comes in a set of this size*, which the setter might have used as a hidden theme. For a set of 12 your mind might then jump to months, Zodiac signs, Chinese Zodiac signs, birthstones, disciples of Jesus, days of Christmas, etc. - you can then try and spot whether each member of the set maps to one of the answers in some way. A lot of puzzles work in this thematic way. Of course the main advice is: practice makes perfect! Keep puzzling and keep learning :)